# How to update a zone inside a component when action is triggered from the container

Tags: ajax, tapestry

I have a page : Test.tml which contain a select and a component :

```
       <t:zone t:id="zone1" t:clientId="zone1">
        <form t:id="form" id="form" method="post">
            <p>
                <select t:type="select" t:id="simpleSelect" t:clientId="simpleSelect" t:value="simpleSelect" t:model="selectList" t:zone="zone1" />
            </p>
        </form>
  <div t:type="SimpleTestComponent" t:id="simpleTestComponent" ></div>
</t:zone>
```

In Test.java, i catch the event :

```
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "simpleSelect")
public Object changeOnSelect(String value) {
    return zone1.getBody();
}
```

which well update zone1

And i have a component which also contain a select and a zone to update; the content of the component select depend of the container select form value, so i need to update also the content of component. If i don't have a zone inside my component it works well, but it's not the case.

inside SimpleTestComponent.tml, i have :

```
   <form t:id="form" id="form" method="post">
        <p>
            <select t:type="select" t:id="nameSelect" t:clientId="nameSelect" t:value="nameSelected" t:model="nameList" t:zone="zoneComponent"/>
        </p>
    </form>
     <t:zone t:id="zoneComponent" t:clientId="zoneComponent">
    <p>${nameSelected}</p></t:zone>
```

and in SimpleTestComponent.java =>

```
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "nameSelect")
public Object valueChanged() {
    return zoneComponentId.getBody();
}
```

I catch the select change, and i update the value.

What i want now is to be able to also update the content of SimpleTestComponent when the select is changed from Test.tml. If i include simpleTestComponent inside zone1, i have an error, about the zone inside simpleTestComponent, and i return a MultiZoneUpdate when i trigger the valueChanged event in Test.java, with zone1 and the component zone (i put a public getter on zone component), i also have an error, so what's the solution ... ?

I'm not sure to be perfectly clear, thx for reading. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your embedded zone (zoneComponent) available to containing components:

```
public class SimpleTestComponent
{
    public Zone getZoneComponent()
    {
        return zoneComponentId;
    }
}
```

and then return that zone from your event handler in your Test class:

```
public class Test
{
    @InjectComponent
    private SimpleTestComponent simpleTestComponent;

    @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "simpleSelect")
    public Object changeOnSelect(String value)
    {
        return simpleTestComponent.getZoneComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: It  almost worked, zone's compoenent is well refreshed, but ids are automatically generated and replaced original ids. And I have an error : "Could not find zone element 'zoneComponent' to update on change of element 'nameSelect_12d94ae9b75".

Comment: Ok i found, so html id was regenerated when i used t:clientId "zoneComponentId" became "zoneComponentId_12d94c0c4bf" i specified id="zoneComponentId" instead of t:clientId="zoneComponentId", it works even if it's not perfect. Thx for your help.